# Why does libapache2-mod-php5 get removed whenever I upgrade apache2?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, package-management, apache2, php

I hope someone can help me figure out what is going on with my apache upgrades. For years, whenever I upgrade apache2, it tries to install `apache2-mpm-itk` even though I use the prefork module `apache2-mpm-prefork` and `libapache2-mod-php5` is removed causing all my php files on my site to be downloaded thus exposing the php source code. Reinstalling `libapache2-mod-php5` prevents the PHP files from being downloaded but of course I need to go change any passwords exposed in the files. Anyone know what is causing this? If related to `apache2-mpm-itk` trying to install each time, anyway to prevent it? It appears `apache2-mpm-itk` does not actually get installed when all done. The output of the apt-get install is below:

Module Index
 Update Packages
 Now updating apache2 ..
 Installing package(s) with command apt-get -y install apache2 ..
 Reading package lists...
 Building dependency tree...
 Reading state information...
 The following extra packages will be installed:
 **apache2-mpm-itk** apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
 Suggested packages:
 apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom
 **The following packages will be REMOVED:

 apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5

 The following NEW packages will be installed:

 apache2-mpm-itk**
 The following packages will be upgraded:
 apache2 apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common
 3 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
 Need to get 1574 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 8714 kB disk space will be freed.

// removed URLs so I could post

- SECURITY UPDATE: HTTP header replacement via HTTP trailers (LP: #1425141)
- debian/patches/CVE-2013-5704.patch: don't merge trailers by default
  and add a "MergeTrailers" directive to revert to previous behaviour
  to include/http_core.h, include/httpd.h, modules/http/http_filters.c,
  modules/http/http_request.c, modules/loggers/mod_log_config.c,
  modules/proxy/mod_proxy_http.c, modules/proxy/proxy_util.c,
  server/core.c, server/protocol.c.
- CVE-2013-5704

  -- Marc Deslauriers  Thu, 05 Mar 2015 12:40:00 -0500

  apt-listchanges: Mailing root: apt-listchanges: changelogs for server1
  Fetched 1574 kB in 3s (521 kB/s)
  (Reading database ... 190291 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to replace apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 (using .../apache2_2.2.22-  1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb) ...
  Unpacking replacement apache2 ...
  Preparing to replace apache2.2-bin 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 (using .../apache2.2-bin_2.2.22- 1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb) ...
  Unpacking replacement apache2.2-bin ...
  Preparing to replace apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 (using .../apache2.2-common_2.2.22- 1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb) ...
  Unpacking replacement apache2.2-common ...
  Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
  Processing triggers for ufw ...
  Processing triggers for man-db ...
  **dpkg: apache2-mpm-prefork: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:

  libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2-mpm-prefork (>> 2.0.52) | apache2-mpm-itk; however:

  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is to be removed.

  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.

  libapache2-mod-cloudflare depends on apache2; however:

  Package apache2 is not configured yet.

  Package apache2-mpm-prefork which provides apache2 is to be removed.

  (Reading database ... 190285 files and directories currently installed.)

  Removing apache2-mpm-prefork ...**
- Stopping web server apache2
  ... waiting ...done.
  Selecting previously unselected package apache2-mpm-itk.
  (Reading database ... 190286 files and directories currently installed.)
  Unpacking apache2-mpm-itk (from .../apache2-mpm-itk_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb) ...
  Setting up apache2.2-bin (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) ...
  Setting up apache2.2-common (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) ...
  Setting up apache2-mpm-itk (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) ...
- Starting web server apache2
  ...done.
  (Reading database ... 190285 files and directories currently installed.)
  **Removing libapache2-mod-php5 ...

  Module php5 disabled.**
  To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
  Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) ...
  .. install complete.

Comment: Install `aptitude` and do `aptitude why apache2-mpm-itk`. It might provide useful information.

Comment: It is not installed... `ubuntu@server1:~$ sudo aptitude why apache-mpm-itk
E: No package named "apache-mpm-itk" exists.`

Comment: `apache2-`, not `apache-`. And bold text is not worth whatever you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, so what does this indicate?, `ubuntu@server1:~$ sudo aptitude why apache2-mpm-itk
i   libapache2-mod-php5 Depends apache2-mpm-prefork (> 2.0.52) | apache2-mpm-itk`